# @BeforeStep doesn't get called

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to use the @BeforeStep /@AfterStep hooks but it seems that the tags doesn't get called. But the @After /@Before hooks work just fine.

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.BeforeStep;

@BeforeStep
public void before_step(Scenario scenario, Step step){
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
@AfterStep
public void afterStep(){
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
@After
public void afterTest() {
    System.out.println("after test");
}
@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    System.out.println("before test");
}
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In the past, I was using info.cukes group but today I changed them to io.cucumber so I can use @AfterStep and @BeforeStep but to no avail. The @After and @Before hooks worked fine in the past with info.cukes and also now with io.cucumber.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try importing library from cucumber's io package instead of cucumber.api

below are the classes

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.AfterStep;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeStep;
```

Can you add following dependencies too..

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hello @Rakesh Singh Chouhan.I've tried these imports (I had to upgrade the version from 4.2.0 to 6.0.0) but it still didn't work.First I tried with AfterStep/BeforeStep from io.cucumber.java and After/Before from cucumber.api.java and the Step Hooks didn;t work but After/Before still worked ,but after I also changed After and Before to be imported from io.cucumber.java and with these imports not even After/Before worked. By working I mean they don't get called.

Comment: I have edit the answer please add the missing dependencies as I can see you have cucumber-java8 but there is no cucumber-java.

Comment: I've added these imports but I have the same problem. I already had cucumber-java (I've changed it from cucumber-java8) but I forgot to edit the imports.

Comment: Do you have your project in any remote repository? where I can look at it. As it is difficult to understand what all things you have in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the full project.But I will try in 2/3 hours to make a new project(maven) with basic steps and to see if there I have the same problem there and maybe I can share that new project.

Comment: I have a reference project @ https://github.com/racchouhan12/SeleniumCucumber5 but I am not using Before and after steps.

Comment: I've made a dummy project and it worked on him.(the @AfterStep/BeforeStep) ,the only difference I think it was that i've imported the cucumber for the runner from io.cucumber.I've also made the change on the main project but to no success yet.I will post the answer if I can find it.